# Hudson + How to update files from more than one branch

Tags: svn, tortoisesvn, hudson

I am using SVN with Hudson for build. I have two branches in SVN, say Branch1 and Branch2. I need files from both the branch for the build. How can i get files from more than one branch using hudson? If i give branch2 url also in hudson SVN plugin, it is giving error like E155000: 'C:\Hudson_CI\jobs\SVN_TEST\workspace' is already a working copy for a different URL; Please guide.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should not need files from 2 branches to do a build. A branch is (supposed to be) a complete copy of your source code. So, you've got something fundamentally wrong there to begin with. Checking out *component1* and *component2* to do a build is OK, but checking out *branch1* and *branch2* of the **same** component is not the way SVN (or any tools that work with SVN) are designed to work.

However, in regards to your question, Hudson can check out from two (and more) different locations.

When you configure **Repository URL**, below it is **Local module directory (optional)**. When using more than 1 URL to do a checkout, you must give different folders (under your workspace) to the different check outs. Call them `branch1` and `branch2` in your cases.

Once the checkout is complete, you can reference them through `${WORKSPACE}/branch1` and `${WORKSPACE}/branch2` respectively.

However, if by chance, you want the checkout files from 2 different URLs to appear under same directory... read my first paragraph. You've really got to rethink what you are doing with SVN. You could still do it in Hudson by running a shell/batch script step that would copy `${WORKSPACE}/branch2` content to `${WORKSPACE}/branch1` after the checkout.